# Searching Solr index for concatenated words

Tags: solr, lucene, n-gram, text-analysis

I'm struggling with two similar use cases.

Here's an example document from my index:

```
{
        "id":"E850AC8D844010AFA76203B390DD3135",
        "brand_txt_en":"Tom Ford",
        "catch_all":["Tom Ford",
          "FT 5163",
          "Tom Ford",
          "FT 5163",
          "DARK HAVANA"],
        "model_txt_en":"FT 5163",
        "brand_txt_en_split":"Tom Ford",
        "model_txt_en_split":"FT 5163",
        "color_txt_en":"DARK HAVANA",
        "material_s":"acetato",
        "gender_s":"uomo",
        "shape_s":"Wayfarer",
        "lens_s":"cerchiata",
        "modelkey_s":"86_1_FT 5163",
        "sales_i":0,
        "brand_s":"Tom Ford",
        "model_s":"FT 5163",
        "color_s":"DARK HAVANA",
        "_version_":1569456572504997895
}
```

Query: **brand_txt_en_split:tomford**

No results!

Field type is Solr's default one:

```
<fieldType name="text_en_splitting" class="solr.TextField" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" catenateNumbers="1" generateNumberParts="1" splitOnCaseChange="1" generateWordParts="1" catenateAll="0" catenateWords="1"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" catenateNumbers="0" generateNumberParts="1" splitOnCaseChange="1" generateWordParts="1" catenateAll="0" catenateWords="0"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

I expect WordDelimiterFilterFactory to generate "tomford" token by concatenating words but it looks like that's not working as expected.

The 'inverse' use case is:

```
{ 
   ...  "model_txt_en_split": "The Clubmaster", ...
}
```

I want that document to be found after this query: 
**club master**

I guess I should use EdgeNGram filter for the latter case, but really can't get how to do that.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WordDelimiterFilterFactory` has the `catenateWords` and `catenateAll`. It works where you have :

```
catenateWords: (integer, default 0) If non-zero, maximal runs of word parts will be joined: "hot-spot-sensor's" -> "hotspotsensor"

catenateAll: (0/1, default 0) If non-zero, runs of word and number parts will be joined: "Zap-Master-9000" -> "ZapMaster9000"`
```

To remove the space between the words please try the below filter.

```
<filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="(\s+)" replacement="" replace="all" />
```

Once you add/update the schema.xml. Restart the server and re-index the data.

You can try the below fieldType for you field name.

```
<analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="4" maxGramSize="25"/>
</analyzer>
```

Input String: `"John Oliver W Clane"`

Tokenizer to Filter: `"John Oliver W Clane"`

Output Tokens :

```
"John", "John ", "John O", "John Ol", "John Oli", "John Oli", "John Oliv", "John Olive", "John Oliver", "John Oliver ", "John Oliver W", "John Oliver W "
, "John Oliver W C", "John Oliver W Cl", "John Oliver W Cla", "John Oliver W Clan", "John Oliver W Clane".
```

There is another filter you can try the same .

```
<filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="4" maxGramSize="25"/>
```

You can read more about the analyzers and filters [Solr Analyzers and Filters](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-WordDelimiterFilter)

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately that's not an answer to my question. I mean: how can I add a token made by concatenation of all other tokens, exactly? 
In your example: "hot spot sensor s" -> "hotspotsensor"

Comment: I have updated the answer. Try using the PatternReplaceFilterFactory. Once you add/update the schema.xml. Restart the server and re-index the data.